# Security of RDPs and infected host system

Tags: windows, rdp

I currently use a lot of Remote Desktop Connections and even mRemoteNG and I am curious, do key loggers and other security threats have the ability to see what I type and do on the RDPs? Can they piggy back on the connections?

I am pretty sure that all keys will be logged but should the host machine in some way have a hidden infection does using VMs and RDP really add an additional layer of protection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can "piggy back" on the connections because keystrokes are first handled by the operating system and then sent to the correct Window. VMs and RDP work if you can easily reset the machines to a clean state. The golden rule is then to use your OS from which your run your RDP (or on which your hypervisor runs) only to access these services and for nothing else.